# App wont connect to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All, I am trying to connect my Android App to Firebase - I have no idea why it's not working and even using a blank activity with the simple suggested lines of code to connect to Firebase isn't working. I have tired going through the manual setup with Firebase and when I run my app, the check for connection is never satisfied. Anyone have any idea what's going on? I have disabled my antivirus and firewall (Windows 10) and still nothing...

Anybody have any idea? All I am getting from my run window:

D/FA: Connected to remote service

V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4

V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

In my Manifest I have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In my build.gradle file, I have followed the firebase instructions:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

And my build.gradle app has the following:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
```

Then using the suggested method from Firebase to write to the database:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

I have another program that I writing that is more elaborate, however I get the same lack of activity / connection to Firebase - can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? I don't get any error messages etc. nothing

Main Activity

[Main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDQzo.png)

[Error messages in Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MQYH.png)

Comment: Would you please post whole code and steps you have done ?

Comment: I created a new project in Firebase console
Followed instructions, added json file and made the necessary amendments to the gradle files
Then used the code that's  pasted above and nothing
None of my apps  are working with Firebase

Comment: can you post your activity pls

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 myRef.setValue("Hello, World!").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d("Firebase", "Success");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("Failure Firebase", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

or

```
myRef.setValue("Hello, World!", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference dataReference) {
            Log.d("Failure Firebase", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nope - I added that file - it wont compile without the json file if you forget

Comment: It can be maven repository

Comment: You can see the problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

All - this is now resolved...

There appeared to be an emulator issue with the network - I was getting an error:

```
W/ManagedChannelImpl: [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
```

All sorted now!

Thanks for helping me out!!!!!